# Al registrar y luego buscar todos con mongoose retorna un array vacio

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Luego de registrar en una colección llamada "mensajes" y luego buscar todos los mensajes este retorna un array vacío. Estoy usando mlab luego de que registro un mensaje reviso la base de datos y ahi esta el nuevo registro. Una vez registrado luego busco todos los mensajes y los retorno en un evento usando socket.io pero esto retorna un array vacio.

```
app.post('/mensajes', (req, res)=>{
    Mensajes.create(req.body, function(err, result) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err)
            res.send(err);
            return;
        }
    
    });
    Mensajes.find({}, function(err, mensajes) {
        if(err) {
            res.send(err);
            return;
        }
        console.log(mensajes)
        //emitir evento 'mensaje'
        io.emit('mensaje', mensajes)
    });

});
```

El endpoint "/mensajes" se activa cuando envio una petición post desde el index.html. Luego de guardar el mensaje como ven busco todos los mensajes para retornalos. 

Lo que provoca que en mi index.html obtenga valores "undefined":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el index.html basicamente escucho el evento "mensaje" para luego llenar el div:

```
   //escuchar el evento 'mensaje'
    socket.on('mensaje', (data)=>{
        console.log(data)
        agregarMensajes(data);
    });
    function agregarMensajes(data){
        //template string `
        $("#mensajes").append(`<strong> ${data.username}: </strong> ${data.mensaje}<br>`)
        //auto deslisar el scroll del div.
        $("#mensajes").animate({
            scrollTop: $('#mensajes').get(0).scrollHeight
        },100);
    }
```

Lo raro es que todos los mensajes se registran y cuando recargo la pagina e ingreso con otro usuario se listan los mensaje para ello llamo a un endpoint de tipo get, este retorna todos los mensajes:

```
app.get('/mensajes', (req, res)=>{
    Mensajes.find({}, function(err, mensajes) {
        if(err) {
            res.send(err);
            return;
        }
        res.json(mensajes);
    });
});
```

Este es mi modelo Mensajes:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mensajesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username:{
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    mensaje:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        min: 5,
        max: 10
    },
    fecha:{
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Mensaje', mensajesSchema)
```

Luego de que empiezo a registrar varios mensajes veo el console.log y veo que se retornan los ultimos mensajes menos el ultimo que se registra pero sigue apareciendo undefined.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco sus sugerencias.
Gracias.

Comment: Hola amigos lo he solucionado agregando async al endpoint /mensajes app.post('/mensajes', async (req, res)=>{ ... pero no logro entender por que no funciono el metodo clasico. Por que solo me retornaba los mensajes anteriores menos el ultimo que se registraba.

Comment: De esta forma quedo el codigo.. https://imgur.com/a/OleTJJq recomiendan usar async y await?

Comment: acá no resolvemos tareas :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Tu problema es el manejo de los procesos asíncronos implícitos al usar las funciones `callback` en los métodos `create` y `find` de tu modelo.

Actualmente tienes lo siguiente:

```js
Mensajes.create(document, callback_1);
Mensajes.find({}, callback_2);
```

Javascript no esperará por el resultado del método `create`, simplemente delegará el mismo a la función `callback_1`. Y se ejecutará inmediatamente el llamado a `find`.

Esto se conoce como condición de carrera (*race condition*), Ganará quien devuelva primero un resultado. Por lo general, un proceso de lectura de datos siempre es más rápido que un proceso de escritura.

Por otro lado, en tu función `callback_1` no retornas ningún resultado al cliente, excepto si hay un error. Esto se traduce, en que si quisieras devolver el resultado de la inserción del documento en la base de datos, lo más seguro es que obtuvieras un error parecido al siguiente:

> `Cannot set headers because response was already sent`

Y es que al ganar el método `find` sobre el método `create`, la respuesta enviada por `callback_2` cerraría el proceso (*request/response*), haciendo imposible enviar otra respuesta al cliente, que la ya enviada.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Una solución es realizar el llamado a `find` desde `callback_1`. De esta forma tendrías la certeza de que el mismo se ejecutaría después de que el proceso de creación del documento se realice con éxito. Por ejemplo:

```js
Mensaje.create(document, (error, result) => {
  // aqui estoy dentro de callback_1
  if(error) {
    return res.status(500).json({
      error: error.message
    });
  }
  // si no hay error, significa que el documento se creó
  Mensaje.find({}, (error, mensajes) => {
    // aqui estoy dentro de callback_2
    if(error) {
      return res.status(500).json({
        error: error.message
      });
    }
    // ahora que tenemos los datos podemos enviar la respuesta al cliente
    return res.status(200).json({
      result: result, // tengo acceso a la variable result de callback_1
      mensajes: mensajes
    });
  }); // fin callback_2
}); // fin callback_1
```

De esta forma, el resultado sólo se envía en caso de error (en `callback_1` o en `callback_2`) o si la creación y posterior búsqueda de documentos es positiva.

**Usando `async / await`**

Otra opción es usar una función tipo `async` y esperar el resultado con `await`. Ello implica envolver el código en un bloque `try / catch` para capturar los posibles errores. Por ejemplo:

```js
app.post('/mensajes', async (req, res)=>{ // <= declaro async
  try {
    let result = await Mensaje.create(req.body);
    let mensajes = await Mensaje.find({});
    return res.status(200).json({
      result, mensajes
    });
  }
  catch(error) {
    return res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
  }
});
```

Cualquiera de las dos formas es aceptable. Sin embargo, tal vez usando `async / await` el código es un poco menos confuso.

Comment: Excelente Mauricio tu código te da toda la razòn, la verdad recién estoy iniciando con mongodb, espero con este inconveniente haber aprendido con lo que indicas.. si creo que con async el codigo es menos confuso sin embargo habrán casos en donde debería de usar los callback